# Should I have two separate tables if they differ by only one column?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema, foreign-key-relationship

I am developing a movie database with both credits for actors and filmmakers. Currently, the actor and filmmaker credits are all together in one table because they only differ by one column (the "role_id" foreign key never gets used for filmmaker credits -- it is always NULL). Is it still best practice to keep them in one table ("movie_credits") or would it be better to separate ("actor_credits" and "filmmaker_credits")?

Here is a very basic schema I've defined, and I'm including some example data in it:

```
movie_credits
+----+-----------+---------+---------------+----------+
| id | talent_id | role_id |   identity_id | title_id |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------+----------+
|  1 |         1 | 1       |             1 |        1 |
|  2 |         2 | 2       |             1 |        2 |
|  3 |         1 | NULL    |             2 |        4 |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------+----------+

talent
+----+------------+-----------+
| id | first_name | last_name |
+----+------------+-----------+
|  1 | Clint      | Eastwood  |
|  2 | Sylvester  | Stallone  |
+----+------------+-----------+

roles
+----+---------------+
| id |     name      |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | Walt Kowalski |
|  2 | Rocky Balboa  |
+----+---------------+

identities
+----+--------------+
| id |   identity   |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | actor        |
|  2 | director     |
|  3 | producer     |
|  4 | screenwriter |
+----+--------------+

titles
+----+-----------------+
| id |      name       |
+----+-----------------+
| 1  | Gran Torino     |
| 2  | Rocky           |
| 3  | Creed           |
| 4  | American Sniper |
+----+-----------------+
```

If you see a completely different way of structuring the data for this scenario, please let me know. I am open to any solution that may be even more efficient and scalable.

Comment: My first thought would be that, since the same person can take on multiple "identities" (your term) on different pictures, or even on the same picture, your current solution would be more flexible than having separate tables for cast & crew. There is room for improvement, but I would need to spend some time on it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to clarify, I am not actually thinking of separating the "talent" table into actors and filmmakers, but rather was considering splitting "movie credits" into two tables ("actor_credits" would have the "role_id" column and "filmmaker_credits" would have the "identity_id" column)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, both actor and filmmaker are persons.

So they must be stored in a single table.

We must avoid null and redundancy from the database. But in this case, making the extra table will increase much overhead than the profit of removing null.

Also, you can simply assign filmmaker as the role to avoid nulls.
That is, there will be a role named filmmaker.

Comment: I had considered the idea of assigning "filmmaker" as a role, but the role_id column needs to be an integer, so I would need to add "filmmaker" to the roles table, which is very large and really meant to be a list of fictional characters with different information about each one.